# How do I render two links with a pipeline as separator?

Tags: navigation

How do I render two links with a pipeline as separator? For example, `$edit` and `$action` are links generated using `\Drupal::l()`. Then, I edited them with the following code.

```
if ($edit) {  
  $action =  $edit . ' | ' .  $action;     
}
else {                 
 $action = $action;          
}                    

$action  = $action . "<span class = 'loader'></span>";`
```

Instead of links, the page is displaying HTML markup as plain text, but no links.

```
<a href="/en/node/51357/edit?ser=383&amp;rel=49064&amp;env=1&amp;destination=group/39/">Edit</a> | <a href="/archive/" class="archive_deployedRelease" nid="51357">Archive</a><span class = 'loader'></span>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: Move your last line to before the if statement (make it the 1st line).

Comment: what? your question is not clear, are you sure you are in drupal 8? you pass $action to your twig template and then what?  the result you showed seems correct, two `a` tags with a span. what is the problem?

Comment: it should render as link but it displaying html itself

Comment: What happens if you remove the pipeline? does it work?

Answer (score 1):

What you see as displayed HTML is escaped by Twig. Only safe markup is not escaped.

`l()` produces safe markup, but if you add something to it, the complete string becomes unsafe.

You can use an inline template to get around this problem.

```
if ($edit) {
  $action = [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '{{ edit }} | {{ action }}<span class = 'loader'></span>',
    '#context' => [
      'edit' => $edit,
      'action' => $action,
    ],
  ];
}
```